# Python loop llenar un dataframe con datos

Tags: python, pandas

Cómo puedo lograr crear una función que me sirva para llenar los valores en la columna de tipo de cambio

```
df1

"date"     "value"     "Exchange_Rate"
2019-Jan    35691
2019-Jan    17076
2019-Dec    988
2019-Dec    1996


df2

"exchange_rate" "date"     "real_or_forecast"

19.126386   2019-Jan  real
19.197585   2019-Feb  real
19.269133   2019-Mar  real
19.089059   2019-Apr  real
19.042815   2019-May  real
19.142962   2019-Jun  real
NaN         2019-Jul  forecast
NaN         2019-Aug  forecast
19.237154   2019-Sep  forecast
NaN         2019-Oct  forecast
19.559262   2019-Nov  forecast
NaN         2019-Dec  forecast
19.559262       2020-Jan  forecast

def get_fill_currency(df):   
    for value in df['date']
        if df1['date'] == date :
            return value['exchange_rate']

df1

"date"     "value"     "Exchange_Rate"
2019-Jan    35691        19.126386       
2019-Jan    17076        19.126386
2019-Dec    988          19.559262
2019-Dec    1996         19.559262
```

Comment: Hola Juan ¿Lo que buscas es llenar la columna "Exchange_Rate" de df1 con los datos de "exchange_rate" de df2 en función de la fecha? ¿Las columnas date de que tipo son? ¿cadenas o DateTime?

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿quieres interpolar los valores nulos? ¿En caso afirmativo con que método? Lo digo porque a `2019-Dec` le correspondería `NaN` de no ser así...

Comment: No conozco mucho sobre los métodos de interpolación, pero la idea sería primero interpolar los datos del modelo de forecast para el tipo de cambio, está tabla tiene fechas unicas ya que es una serie temporal y de ahí aplicar los valores de forecast Al df1 que tiene muchas fechas repetidas.

Comment: solamente df2 es un time series, las columnas de fechas son typo datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para interporlar los valores nulos tienes a tu disposición [`pandas.Series.interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html), por defecto se lleva a cabo una interpolación lineal:

> ```
> >>> df2['exchange_rate'].interpolate(method="linear")
>
> 0     19.126386
> 1     19.197585
> 2     19.269133
> 3     19.089059
> 4     19.042815
> 5     19.142962
> 6     19.174359
> 7     19.205757
> 8     19.237154
> 9     19.398208
> 10    19.559262
> 11    25.057631
> 12    30.555999
> ```

pero tienes múltiples métodos implementados. Por ejemplo usando el valor previo no nulo (padding):

> ```
> >>> df2['exchange_rate'].interpolate(method="pad")
>
> 0     19.126386
> 1     19.197585
> 2     19.269133
> 3     19.089059
> 4     19.042815
> 5     19.142962
> 6     19.142962
> 7     19.142962
> 8     19.237154
> 9     19.237154
> 10    19.559262
> 11    19.559262
> 12    30.555999
> ```

Los datos son los de tu ejemplo, excepto para la última fila (2020-Jan), para la que he cambiado el valor de 19.559262 a 30.555999 para que se vea la diferencia entre métodos.

En cuanto a trasladar el valor a df1 desde df2, ciertamente hay muchas formas, incluidas usar un `for` como planteas o una función con `pandas.DataFrame.apply`. No obstante creo que la forma más óptima para estos casos es usar [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.Series.map.html), la cual permite tomar los valores a mapear desde otra serie, usando los índices como clave.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df1_data = io.StringIO("""\
    date    value
2019-Jan    35691
2019-Jan    17076
2019-Dec    988
2019-Dec    1996
""")

df2_data = io.StringIO("""\
exchange_rate       date  real_or_forecast
    19.126386   2019-Jan              real
    19.197585   2019-Feb              real
    19.269133   2019-Mar              real
    19.089059   2019-Apr              real
    19.042815   2019-May              real
    19.142962   2019-Jun              real
    NaN         2019-Jul          forecast
    NaN         2019-Aug          forecast
    19.237154   2019-Sep          forecast
    NaN         2019-Oct          forecast
    19.559262   2019-Nov          forecast
    NaN         2019-Dec          forecast
    19.559262   2020-Jan          forecast
""")

df1 = pd.read_csv(df1_data, sep="\s+")
df2 = pd.read_csv(df2_data, sep="\s+")

df1["exchange_rate"] = df1["date"].map(df2.set_index('date')['exchange_rate']
                                          .interpolate(method="linear")
                                      )
```

> ```
> >>> df1
>
>        date  value  exchange_rate
> 0  2019-Jan  35691      19.126386
> 1  2019-Jan  17076      19.126386
> 2  2019-Dec    988      19.559262
> 3  2019-Dec   1996      19.559262
> ```

Si quieres que la interpolación se aplique al propio df2 in-place, aplícala antes:

```
df2["exchange_rate"].interpolate(method="linear", inplace=True)
df1["exchange_rate"] = df1["date"].map(df2.set_index('date')['exchange_rate'])
```

### Edición

Para aplicar `pandas.Series.map` es necesario que la serie de la que se toman los datos tenga como índice la columna que se usa para asociar los valores de ambos DataFrames, `date` en nuestro ejemplo. Esto es así, porque cada valor de `date` de `df1` se va a buscar en el índice de la serie pasada a `map` y el valor asociado a ese índice (de encontrarse) es el usado para poblar la columna `exchange_rate` de `df1`.

Si en nuestro caso la columna `date` ya fuera el índice de `df2`, bastaría con:

```
df1["exchange_rate"] = df1["date"].map(df2['exchange_rate'].interpolate(method="linear"))
```

si es índice en ambos DataFrames entonces podemos hacer:

```
df1["exchange_rate"] = df1.index.map(df2['exchange_rate'].interpolate(method="linear"))
```

Comment: set index es sirve para poner una columna x como indice no?, si esta columna date ya es indice que hago? para trabajar con mapo es forzoso que la serie que se usa tenga indice?

Comment: Si, es forzoso porque se usa como clave para el mapeo. Es decir, el valor date de df1 se busca en el índice de la serie y el valor asociado a ese índice se usa para substituir. Si tu columna date ya es índice no necesitas set_index. ¿date es también indice en df1 o solo de df2?

Comment: ya veo, usé el dato como
df2["exchange_rate"] = df1["date"].map(df3['exchange_rate']), ya que el indice estaba seteado, no valía la pena setearlo de nuevo

Comment: oye y de casualidad sabrás hacer funciones para multiplicar columnas?

Comment: La cuestion aqui es que igual estoy intentando aprender a usar los loops fors y todo para realizar iteraciones

Comment: Juan usar loop cuando usas pandas/numpy es generalmente contraproducente porque es infinitamente menos eficiente que las operaciones vectorizadas que ofrecen dichas librerías (dónde las operaciones se mantienen a nivel de código C compilado y muy optimizado para realizar operaciones en arrays/matrices). Los ciclos se deben reducir a cuando sean totalmente imprescindibles y necesitemos algo que solo el potencial dinámico de Python puro pueda darnos. Realmente sería otra pregunta, pero ¿Cómo quieres multiplicar las columnas?

Comment: siento mucho las confusiones, en serio que estoy aprendiendo bastante y mas con esta comunidad tan amigable de python.

Comment: la enorme cantidad de preguntas se debe a que eventualmente quiero calcular NPVs a partir de miles de registros, estoy explorando como es que uno se tiene que expresar en python para lograr resultados, te agradezco mucho FSEVILLA